# Rails 4.1 changing rails_admin name

Tags: rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Hi i wanted to change what my rails admin was displaying

I have already fix the code with

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

which was the first error that i got now this is showing , it is a minor bug that i needed to change pls look at the image below

[image]

as you can see it says facebook and i need it to say something else how can i change it? because from previous coding and i recoded it now the problem is the admin says it is a facebook , but it is not what i was expecting any help will do

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in : config/initializers/rails_admin.rb by adding this :

```
config.main_app_name = ['MyApp', 'Admin']
```